# MS Access to SQL Query

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, join

I have few queries that have been migrated to SQL Server from Access DB. The results however are not the same. Below are the queries in Access and SQL. Could anyone please let me know if there is anything wrong with the query.

```
Query 1  in MS Access
SELECT [TableA].Mat, [TableA].Sg, [TableA].Pt, [TableB].[Ptype]
FROM [TableA] INNER JOIN [TableB] ON [TableA].Sg=[TableB].Sg
WHERE ((([TableA].Dl)="04") And [TableB].[Ptype]<>"dummy") - TableFinal

Query2 in MS Access
SELECT DISTINCT TableFinal.Mat, TableFinal.Sg, IIf(TableFinal.Pt Is Null,[TableD].Pt,TableFinal.Pt) AS Pnt, [TableC].[Ptype]
FROM (TableFinal INNER JOIN [TableC] ON TableFinal.Sg=[TableC].Sg) INNER JOIN [TableD] ON ([TableC].Pt=[TableD].Pt) AND (TableFinal.Mat=[TableD].Mat)
WHERE ((([TableC].[Ptype])<>"dummy"));

Combined Query1&2 in SQL
SELECT DISTINCT [TableA].Mat, [TableA].Sg, ISNULL([TableA].Pt, [TableC].Pt) AS Pln, 
[TableB].[Ptype]
FROM  [TableA] INNER JOIN
[TableB] ON [TableA].Sg = [TableB].Sg INNER JOIN
[TableC] ON [TableB].Pt = [TableC].Pt AND 
[TableA].Mat = [TableC].Mat
WHERE ([TableB].[Ptype] <> 'dummy') AND ([TableA].Dl = '04') - Final


Query3 in MS Access
SELECT DISTINCT Final.Mat, Final.Sg, Final.Pt, IIf([TableB].[Ptype] Is Null,Final.[Ptype],[TableB].[Ptype]) AS [Pan] 
INTO Destination
FROM [TableB] RIGHT JOIN Final ON ([TableB].Pt=Final.Pt) AND ([TableB].Sg=Final.Sg);



Query3 in SQL
SELECT DISTINCT Final.Mat, Final.Sg, Final.Pt, 
ISNULL(TableB].[Ptype], Final.[Ptype]) AS [Ptype]
FROM TableB] RIGHT OUTER JOIN
Final ON [TableB].Pt = Final.Pt AND 
[TableB].Sg = Final.Sg
```

Comment: No data is showing up when I use the edited query in SQL. My concern is if I have edited the query in the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure, but I think this is what you intended:

```
--Combined Query1&2 in SQL
SELECT DISTINCT
  [TableA].Mat,
  [TableA].Sg,
  ISNULL([TableA].Pt, [TableC].Pt) AS Pln,
  [TableB].[Ptype]
INTO
  #FINAL
FROM
  [TableA]
  INNER JOIN [TableB] ON [TableA].Sg = [TableB].Sg
  INNER JOIN [TableC] ON [TableB].Pt = [TableC].Pt AND
                         [TableA].Mat = [TableC].Mat
WHERE
  ([TableB].[Ptype] <> 'dummy') AND
  ([TableA].Dl = '04')

--Query3 in SQL
SELECT DISTINCT
  Final.Mat,
  Final.Sg,
  Final.Pln, --Final.Pt,
  ISNULL([TableB].[Ptype], Final.[Ptype]) AS [Ptype]
FROM
  [TableB]
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN #FINAL AS Final ON [TableB].Pt = Final.Pln AND
                                      [TableB].Sg = Final.Sg
```

Comment: Thanks both the query I wrote and the one you provided were the same. There was no Value like '04' after the new load of data hence it was showing no results.